# cytoscape js label display, how to wrap text

Tags: graph, label, styles, cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape.js to display a directed graph and I display 2 properties in a label.

I want to wrap the text and this is said to be possbile in the documentation but I cant get it to work. Can anyone help with the syntax?

```
'label': 'data(name)',
'font-size' : 14
'text-wrap': 'wrap/n'
```

`text-wrap` does not seem to work, it hangs up the graph display.

Do I need to set 'text-max-width'?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You can't add the \n in the text-wrap css property, you are looking for the label property:

```
{
    "selector": ".multiline-manual",
    "style": {
      "text-wrap": "wrap"
    }
  },

  {
    "selector": ".multiline-auto",
    "style": {
      "text-wrap": "wrap",
      "text-max-width": 80
    }
  },
```

One of these classes should be added to the node you want your label to be wrapped. You can do it like this:

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(name)",
        height: "60px",
        width: "60px"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ".multiline-manual",
      style: {
        "text-wrap": "wrap"
      }
    },

    {
      selector: ".multiline-auto",
      style: {
        "text-wrap": "wrap",
        "text-max-width": 80
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "n0",
          name: "This is a very long name and all I have to do is to add a class!"
        },
        classes: "multiline-auto"
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n1",
          name: "Shorter"
        },
        classes: "multiline-auto"
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n2",
          name: "This shouldn't wrap"
        },
        classes: "multiline-manual"
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n3",
          name: "This should\nwrap"
        },
        classes: "multiline-manual"
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "n0",
          target: "n1"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n2"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n3"
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: "dagre",
    padding: 5
  }
}));
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.3.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- cyposcape dagre -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Stephan, very helpful explanation and example